# What is "MacOsUnlockCode" in body request's Remote Wipe Intune?

Tags: macos, azure-active-directory, device, intune

I want to remote wipe device with Intune Graph API, but the docs doesn't provide information about the **"MacOsUnlockCode"** variable : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-wipe?view=graph-rest-1.0#request-body?

I've try not include it and that works in non-apple device. But When I try it in MacOs, I should include it to give 204(HttpStatusCode) , but in the end Azure AD keep notice  : **Wipe Failed** in device action history

{
  "keepEnrollmentData": true,
  "keepUserData": true,
  "macOsUnlockCode": "Mac Os Unlock Code value"
}